# Converting 2.5V and 1.1V from 5V Power Supply with 10ms delay between both!

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, buck, switching-regulator

I'm working on a design where i need to convert 2.5V and 1.1V from 5V power supply respectively. The constraint of design is such that 2.5V rail should come up first and then followed by 1.1V rail. Also, i want output to reach 2.5V with 10ms delay and then another 10ms delay for 1.1V to come up. Is there any off the shelf buck converter which does this? An can you guys suggest what should be the right approach towards this design?

Comment: what currents ? And what is your definition of UP FIRST?

Comment: Hey Trevor! I missed adding the current details- here it goes..  2.5v - 500mA and 1.1V- 4A. UP first means, 2.5V rail should power on first and then 1.1V rail. I want 2.5V to power up in 10ms and then after another 10ms, 1.1V rail should power up..

Comment: Why do you need those 10ms delays?

Answer (score 2):

Because I had some available, I have used an LT3510 in a similar situation. Consult the datasheeet and you will see that it covers your requirements. I'm sure plenty of other devices from other manufacturers will manage as well, just use any supplier's parametric search. There is no lack of buck converters with multiple outputs, and many that offer separate output enables, sequencing features and so on.

If your design includes a microcontroller, it might make more sense to use that for your power sequencing. This could enable you to derive the other rails using simple linear regulators. If your current requirements are low, this may be a cheaper and simpler option.  Using a switching supply for the main supply rails and local linear regulators for subcircuits is a typical practice.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of DC-DC ICs from various manufacturers (LT, AD, TI, Maxim, etc...)  Many of the parts include a soft start that I often use for power up sequencing for FPGA and microcontroller designs.  I have also used LM3881 for some power supply sequencing (controls the enable pin of the DC-DC).  TI has a very nice tool (WebBench) that will show you supplies for your specific requirements.